# Software for Linux OS to create any type of bootable usb drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, bootable

I need a software like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), but for Linux (I didn't find any software like this, I don't know how to install Rufus on Linux Ubuntu) to create any type of bootable flash drive then install whatsoever OS that I want to my ssd.

Comment: *Rufus for Linux* is for Linux, and then you need software for Linux? That's not very clear. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and edit your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen oh sorry for my inconvenience! I was sick and tired yesterday and have typed here as fast as possible but now it was revised!Thanks! :)

Comment: Rufus is for Windows. Probably why it was quoted "Rufus for Linux", as the OP seeks a Linux equivalent.

Comment: That's https://rufus.ie/  OP wants a Linux equivalent

Comment: `mint-stick` on a Mint liveCD, `dd`, etc. can all do it on a *nix system.

Comment: @Mawg I've just found this version that run under Wine in Ubuntu 18.04! But I don't know if it will work properly cause some apps that I've installed from Winehq doesn't works! Have you tryed this rufus version yet? Thanks! :)

Comment: @ivanivan It will work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that isn't a liveCD?Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try it. Why not give it a go? If it works, you can answer your own question, and accept it. Doing so will help others in future. Good luck!

Comment: @Mawg Don't worry! I'll try rufus in ubuntu when I buy my new computer next year!I hope I'll get good prices next year regard to political issues in my country!Thanks for your tips! :)

Comment: You can try Rufus in Ubuntu right now, if you download & burn a live DVD ;-)

Comment: @Mawg Then...I'll try to install Tails right now!What do you think?

Comment: I've tried install Tails in flash drive but rufus don't find any device when I plug it.So,I'm not able to install any OS using rufus in linux ubuntu by now...

Comment: Take a liook at this page. Teh site is alway suseful ... https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus/?platform=linux